# how to call the application titles and other static messages from a service?

Tags: angularjs

here is the code i have tried so far

angular.module('app')

```
.factory('PostMeetUpService', function () {

    var myMtpData = {title: "Post MeetUp",error: "*Required"};
    return {

        getMyMtpData: function () {
            return myMtpData;
        }
    }


});
```

and in Controller as follows:

```
$scope.Mtp_Data = PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData();
```

`{{Mtp_Data.title}}` is the expression  am using in HTML ,

but unable to display the data  . i have also injected the service in the function .

Comment: In controller but a breakpoint on this line: $scope.Mtp_Data = PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData(); and execute PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData(); in console. What do you see?

Comment: this is the error am getting in console Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: I think your service is not getting injected properly.

Comment: post your controller skeleton...

Comment: am just injecting the service name in my controller

Comment: Are your service and controller in the same module? If not then you'll need to load your service module as dependency.

Comment: Also, can you post the complete stack trace from the console error?

Comment: .controller('postCtrl', function ($scope, $state,PostMeetUpService,$stateParams, Event, Terminal, PostService, Auth, Profession, growl, $ionicPopup, $filter, $ionicModal) {

        var dateType = '';
        var timeType = '';
        $scope.Mtp_Data = PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData();

Comment: above you can see how i have injected the service

Comment: can you tell me how can i load the service module as dependency .

Comment: Can you post the error message? I think it might be helpful.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=PostMeetUpServiceProvider%20%3C-%20PostMeetUpService
    at Error (native)

Comment: Is the module same for both service and controller? It shouldn't be that the service is in 'com.xyz.services' and controller is in 'com.xyz.controllers' module. This is critical!

Comment: no the module is different for both

Comment: Check my updated answer. You need to find the place where your controller module is declared and inject the service module. Let me know if you need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('abc');

serviceModule.factory('PostMeetUpService', function () {

    var myMtpData = {title: "Post MeetUp",error: "*Required"};
    return {

        getMyMtpData: function () {
            return myMtpData;
        }
    }
});

var controllerModule = angular.module('xyz', ['abc']);
controllerModule.controller('postCtrl', post);

post.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'PostMeetUpService', '$stateParams', 'Event', 'Terminal', 'PostService', 'Auth', 'Profession', 'growl', '$ionicPopup', '$filter', '$ionicModal'];

function post($scope, $state, PostMeetUpService, $stateParams, Event, Terminal, PostService, Auth, Profession, growl, $ionicPopup, $filter, $ionicModal) { 

var dateType = '';   
var timeType = '';   
$scope.Mtp_Data = PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData();  

}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Modify the factory as:

```
.factory('PostMeetUpService', function () {

    var PostMeetUpServiceFactory = {};

    var _myMtpData = {title: "Post MeetUp",error: "*Required"};
    var _getMyMtpData = function() {
           return _myMtpData;
    }
   PostMeetUpServiceFactory.getMyMtpData = _getMyMtpData ;

   return PostMeetUpServiceFactory;
});
```

Then in controller:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'PostMeetUpService', function($scope, PostMeetUpService) {

$scope.Mtp_Data = PostMeetUpService.getMyMtpData();
}]);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution

Comment: I think there's one line missing in the the service:
return PostMeetUpServiceFactory;

Comment: yes, thank you , i missed it, made an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Bhanu, this is dependency injection where the service factory returns javascript objects and methods.